# Strange error filtering custom post type by acf fields in admin

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm using ACF Pro in Wordpress to define the fields for a custom post type. In the admin, I'm trying to add dropdowns to filter my custom post type in the admin page by various fields and I'm getting a very strange error. When I create a dropdown containing all possible values for that field, every other one that is created does not print out the `<select>` portion of the dropdown. It only prints out the options.

So if I add three filters, size, color and type, and then inspect the html of the admin page near the filter button, it looks like this:

```
<select name="filter_size">
  <option value="">All Sizes</option>
  <option value="small">Small</option>
  <option value="large">Large</option>
</select>
<option value="">All Colors</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<select name="filter_type">
  <option value="">All Types</option>
  <option value="short">Short Sleeve</option>
  <option value="long">Long Sleeve</option>
</select>
```

It refuses to print the second open and close select tags. If I add a forth filter it doesn't work, but the fifth one does. It's only messing up every other filter I add. It doesn't matter what order they are in. The odd numbered ones work, the even ones don't. I know the query is good because each one works individually and even for the ones that aren't display correctly, it is returning all of the values. It just seems to be the select that isn't being printed.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
if (is_admin()) {

    add_action('restrict_manage_posts', function ($post_type) {
        if ('my-cpt' == $post_type) {
            buildAdminDropdownFilter($post_type, 'size', "All Sizes");
            buildAdminDropdownFilter($post_type, 'color', "All Colors");
            buildAdminDropdownFilter($post_type, 'type', "All Types");
        }
    });
});

function buildAdminDropdownFilter($postType, $metaKey, $label) {
    global $wpdb;

    $query_values = $wpdb->get_results( 
      $wpdb->prepare("SELECT distinct meta_value ".
        "  FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta ".
        "  WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ".
        "    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = %s ".
        "    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = %s".
        "  ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value", $postType, $metaKey));

    echo '<select name="filter_'.$metaKey.'">';
    echo '<option value="">'.$label.'</option>';

    $current = $_GET['filter_' . $metaKey] ?? '';
    foreach($query_values as &$data) {
        echo '<option value="'.$data->meta_value.'">'.ucwords($data->meta_value).'</option>';
    }
    echo '</selected>';

}
```

Any ideas what's going on? I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0):

I found it with the help of a co-worker. It was an incredibly stupid little typo. For my closing select tag, I have /selected rather than /select.